# What is the correct way of calling a template function using std::async

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to understand the uses of `std::async`. I wrote below template function to accumulate all the entries in an integral array.

```
template<typename T, int N, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
T parallel_sum(T(&arr)[N], size_t start = 0, size_t end = N - 1) {
    if (end - start < 1000) {
        return std::accumulate(std::begin(arr) + start, std::begin(arr) + end + 1, 0);
    }
    else {
        size_t mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        auto res1 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_sum<T, N>, arr, start, mid);
        auto res2 = parallel_sum(arr, mid + 1, end);
        return res2 + res1.get();
    }
}
```

When I call above function in main I get below compilation error (along with some more):

> error C2672: 'std::async': no matching overloaded function found

Why am I getting this error? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to preserve reference semantics.

Change is line:

```
auto res1 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_sum<T, N>, arr, start, mid);
```

to:

```
auto res1 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_sum<T, N>, std::ref(arr), start, mid);
```